# JQUERY-PHP-MYSQL - Data from Mysql into a existing DIV list did not respond click event

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css

Im a beginner in PHP, MYSQL, JQUERY.

I intended to load a photo gallery (ul) into a div.

The following snippet works well and the style applied to that element and its children works too.

The WHERE clause is enough to load 12 pictures with only one parameter (TabFotosVisivel=1).

Please check the following snippets out:

***INDEX.PHP***

```
<div id="idDivTC">
    <ul>
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TabFotos WHERE TabFotosVisivel=1 ORDER BY TabFotosID DESC LIMIT 0,12");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$caminhoArquivo=$row["TabFotosCamArqMini"];
$descricao=$row["TabFotosDescricao"];
$titulo=$row["TabFotosTitulo"];
echo("<li><img class='claFotoMiniatura' src='".$caminhoArquivo."' title='".$titulo."' alt='".$descricao."'></li>");
}//fim do while
</ul>
</div><!-- /idDivTC -->
```

//-----------style of index.php------------------------

```
#idDivTC ul li {
display:inline;
}
#idDivTC ul li img{
margin:1px;
float:left;
}
```

Now I would like to load into the same structure another gallery and I use Jquery to call a page with pure PHP.

The additional parameter to WHERE clause id 'idLido'.

The code is

//-------------  jquery of index.php----------------------

```
$(".claSubMenu").click(function (){
var idLido=$(this).attr("alt");
$.post("miniatura.php", { idLido:idLido})
.done(function(data) {
var arrayRetorno=new Array();
arrayRetorno=data.split("@");
for (i=0;i<arrayRetorno.length;i++){
$("#idDivTC ul").append(arrayRetorno[i]);
}
});
});
```

***MINIATURA.PHP***

```
<?php
require_once("bd.php");
$idLido=$_POST['idLido'];
$sentenca = "SELECT * FROM TabFotos WHERE TabFotosFKGalerias = ".$idLido." AND    TabFotosVisivel=1";
$result = mysql_query($sentenca);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$titulo=$row['TabFotosTitulo'];
$descricao=$row['TabFotosDescricao'];
$caminhoArquivo=$row['TabFotosCamArqMini'];
$retorno=$retorno."<li><img class='claFotoMiniatura' src='".$caminhoArquivo."'  title='".$titulo."' alt='".$descricao."'></li>@";
}
echo $retorno;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

After retrieve data, Jquery/javascript convert it into an array.

This is my point: I would like, as I said, to read each value of this array and append it to the that element/list, when I invoke

```
$(".claSubMenu").click(function (){
```

through

```
for (i=0;i<arrayRetorno.length;i++){
$("#idDivTC ul").append(arrayRetorno[i]);
}
```

It works, but the style doesnt applied anymore.
It seems to me that the former block is not the same the latter, although they have the same ID.

**Besides**, this click event

```
$("#idDivTC ul li > img").click(function (e){ ...
```

calls a JqueryUI dialog window, but It works **only** on the former structure as well.

How may I achieve my intent?

Thank you

In addition, this is the code to modal dialog window (Ui JQuery):

//--------------------modal of index.php  ----------------

```
$("#idDivTC ul li > img").click(function (e){
e.preventDefault();
var titulo = $(this).attr("title");
var alternativa = $(this).attr("alt");
var imagemObj = new Image();
var caminhoArquivo=$(this).attr("src");
imagemObj.src= caminhoArquivo;
imagemObj.onload = function()
{
var largura=imagemObj.width;
var altura=imagemObj.height;
$(this).clone().dialog({
title: function (){
return titulo+" - "+caminhoArquivo;
},
modal: true,
resizable: false, 
draggable: true,
width: function(){
return largura;
}
//fim da funcao da largura
});//fim da da this clone
};// fim da imagem load
});
```

//-----------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, use event delegation to attach your click handlers: `$("#idDivTC ul li > img").click(...)` becomes `$("#idDivTC ul").on("click", "img", ...)`.

The event isn't fired for the newly created elements because they don't have any click events bound to them.

Comment: Dear ethagnawl, I try this code

    $("#idDivTC ul").on("click", "img", function(event){
    alert("test");
     });

but no luck.

Comment: Bingo, ethagnawl: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? If you're using pre 1.7, you'll need to replace `on` with `delegate` and reverse the first two parameters.